# Not able to interpolate inside *ngFor

Tags: angular

I'm trying to interpolate inside *ngFor .Each tag consist of *ngIf.The value of Particular_id I get after Intepolation is 10,20. So if=Particular_id = 10 it should print Base Module.
Its not printing anything.What have I done wrong?
My json format

```
{
    "Item_description" : [{
        "quantity" :[10,20,30,40],
        "particular" : [20,30,40],
        "description" : ["10","20","30"]
}]
}
```

**Data is in this format : [10,20,30] in json** .

How to manipulate data and make it

```
["id":10,"id":20,"id":30]
```

Code :

.ts :

```
purchase_id=[];
for(var i=0;i< data.Item_description.length;i++) {
this.particular_id[i] = data.Item_description[i].particular_id;
 //this.particular_id["id"+i] is this possible?
}
```

.html

```
 <td *ngFor="let Particular_id  of particular_id">
            <ul>
              <li>{{Particular_id}}</li>
           <li *ngIf="Particular_id === 10">  Base Module</li>
           <li *ngIf="Particular_id === 20"> Advance sta </li>
           <li *ngIf="Particular_id === 30">  Custom Tabl</li> 
           </ul>
    </td>
```

Comment: Use the [map operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: How to manipulate data using map operator ? from [1,2,3] to ['1d':1,'id: 2,'id':3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this method on transforming your data from `[10, 20, 30]` to an Array of Objects `[{"id":10},{"id":20}, {"id":30}]`

```
const data = [10, 20, 30];

this.list = data.map(id => ({ id }));  // [{"id":10},{"id":20}, {"id":30}];

console.log(transform[0].id);     // 10 
console.log(transform[1].id);     // 20
console.log(transform[2].id);     // 30
```

> **NOTE:** You can't have a result of **["id":10,"id":20,"id":30]** since it would trigger an error of:
>
> *"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"*
>
> You can only store **strings, numbers, boolean and objects** in an array.
>
> There's no valid type for **['id': 10]** without **{}** inside.

**So on your template you can iterate them through:**

**1.) NgFor and NgIf**

```
<td *ngFor="let item of list">
  <ul>
     <li>{{ item.id }}</li>
     <li *ngIf="item.id === 10">  Base Module</li>
     <li *ngIf="item.id === 20"> Advance sta </li>
     <li *ngIf="item.id === 30">  Custom Tabl</li> 
  </ul>
</td>
```

**2.) NgFor and NgSwitch**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list">

   <div [ngSwitch]="item.id">
     <div *ngSwitchCase="10">I am 10</div>
     <div *ngSwitchCase="20">I am 20</div>
     <div *ngSwitchCase="30">I am 30</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Had created a [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-list-extract-assign-id) for your reference

Comment: So, in my case 'data' will be 'data.Item_description.quantity' right?

Comment: @GMB Had updated my answer and provided a Stackblitz demo link as well for your reference and its actual implementation :)

Comment: Its giving data.Item_description.quantity.map  is not a function

Comment: mind if you'll post us a 2 to 3 items inside of your "data" ? That way I can also try to extract the expected data you are looking for and apply it on the stackblitz demo

Comment: @GMB Had updated the Stackblitz demo in regards with the update json data you had posted and its working well.

Comment: Now getting this error: ERROR TypeError: "data.Item_description.quantity_id is undefined" . I'm so unlucky :(

Comment: @GMB May i know where did you get the quantity_id ? as currently the one that you had specfied is quantity from data.Item_description.quantity where the quantity has [10, 20, 30] value. I think you must use 'data.Item_description.quantity' for mapping

Comment: I have edited my format in question once again. Please check mam.Thank you for your support. You are my last hope.

Comment: I'm able to do like this     this.quantity = data.Item_description[0].quantity_id.map(num => ({ id: num }));  console.log("Inside datat",this.quantity[1].id);

Comment: @GMB had updated the stackblitz, added 2 methods on it. You can choose based on your preference :)

Comment: @GMB let me know if the updated stackblitz works for you and if there's still need for a fix :) Posted 2 methods, you can choose which would you preferred.

Comment: Now I'm getting like this in console.log: **Data passed** : 0: Array(3) [ 40, 50, 80 ]
​
1: Object { id: 50 }
​
2: Object { id: 80 }
​
length: 3,  ......it is not taking object instead of object .....I have updated my format please check..Thank you..

Comment: Yes, that would be its expected result. By that, you can then iterate it on your template with ngFor

Comment: object 1 is array :( . It should print single value, instead it is priniting array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184857/discussion-between-gmb-and-kshewengger).

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>{{particular_id}}</p>
```

```
   <li *ngIf="Particular_id === 10">  Base Module</li>
   <li *ngIf="Particular_id === 20"> Advance sta </li>
   <li *ngIf="Particular_id === 30">  Custom Tabl</li> 
   </ul>
```

Is there data inside `particular_id`. Try printing it outside `*ngFor`. Can you please add the .ts file as well? It would be easier to solve the issue.

Comment: Added .ts file. How to manipulate array data from [10,20,30] to ["id":10,"id":20,"id":30] or how to access index of array in html ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
<div *ngFor = "let Particular_id of fetchData">
  <ul>
          <li>{{Particular_id.id}}
       <li *ngIf="Particular_id.id == 10">  Base Module</li>
       <li *ngIf="Particular_id.id == 20"> Advance sta </li>
       <li *ngIf="Particular_id.id == 30">  Custom Tabl</li> 
       </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
'id:'+array1.toString().split (',').join( ',id:')
```

Comment: Where should I add this ?